# Enable Syntax highlighting in vim on a per-buffer basis

Tags: vim, syntax-highlighting

I currently have to edit some very large XML files, which slows down syntax highlighting to a point where it's absolutely unusable - it takes multiple seconds to update the screen after a search operation, for example.

When disabling syntax highlighting (`:syn off`), the same operations happen instantaneously. Unfortunately, disabling syntax highlighting appears to happen globally, so all other files now have it disabled as well.

So: Is there a way to only disable syntax highlighting for a given buffer?

Answer (score 20, accepted):

You can set `:syntax manual` and then enable it with `set syntax=ON` in the buffers you like. Also see `:help :syn-manual`.

Comment: i found this quite useful for split windows - so you can `nnoremap <C-W><C-W> :set syntax=off<CR><C-W><C-W>:set syntax=on<cr>` and `nmap <F1> :set syntax=on` (for glitches) - because sometimes i get confused where I am actually editing

Answer (score 7):

Answering my own question: A simple hack would be to force the syntax of the file to something that vim doesn't know how to highlight: `:set syntax=unknown`

However, this seems a bit hacky - maybe there's another solution?

Comment: May be hacky, but is perfect for the occasional time when I want to open a huge file.

Answer (score 4):

For large-file editing I usually use [Chip's `LargeFile` plugin](http://www.vim.org/scripts/script.php?script_id=1506). It disables syntax highlighting, undo database and other features that give trouble with large files.

Answer (score 0):

Old topic, but answer may be helpful to others.;)

This is what I lastly use for switching between syntax ON/OFF in the buffer. The change is local to the buffer. Works OK to me.

```
nnoremap <leader><leader> :call MyLocalSyntaxOnOff()<cr>

function! MyLocalSyntaxOnOff ()
    if getbufvar("%", "&syntax") ==# "OFF"
        setl syntax=ON
        redraw | echo 'Syntax: ON - <space><space> to change.'
    else
        setl syntax=OFF
        redraw | echo 'Syntax: OFF - <space><space> to change.'
    endif
endfunction
```

Just add it to your `.vimrc` and You should by fine.
ADVISE: Set your leader key (my one is `<space>` currently), if not - the standard one should be slash (or backslash(?)) key - `\`.

Best regards.